# How to selectively ignore some inotify events?

Tags: c++, inotify

Lets say I have two processes (simulated in this example with two threads) in a producer-consumer set up. That is, one process writes data to a file, the other process consumes the data in the file, then clears said file.

The set up I currently have, based on bits and pieces I've thrown together from various resources online, is that I should use a lock file to ensure that only one process can access the data file at a time. The producer acquires the lock, writes to the file, then releases the lock. Meanwhile, the consumer waits for modify events with inotify at which point it acquires the lock, consumes the data, and empties the file.

This seems relatively straightforward, but the part that's tripping me up is that when I empty the file out in my consumer thread, it triggers inotify modify event again, which sets off the whole flow again, and ends with the data file being cleared again, thus repeating forever.

I've tried a few ways to work around this problem, but none of them seem quite right. I'm worried doing this wrong will introduce potential race conditions or I'll end up skipping modify events or something.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "pthread.h"
#include "sys/file.h"
#include "sys/inotify.h"
#include "sys/stat.h"
#include "unistd.h"

const char* lock_filename = "./test_lock_file";
const char* data_filename = "./test_data_file";

int AquireLock(char const* lockName) {
  mode_t m = umask(0);
  int fd = open(lockName, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
  umask(m);
  bool success = false;
  if (fd < 0 || flock(fd, LOCK_EX) < 0) {
    close(fd);
    return -1;
  }
  return fd;
}

void ReleaseLock(int fd, char const* lockName) {
  if (fd < 0) return;
  remove(lockName);
  close(fd);
}

void* ConsumerThread(void*) {
  // Set up inotify.
  int file_descriptor = inotify_init();
  if (file_descriptor < 0) return nullptr;
  int watch_descriptor =
      inotify_add_watch(file_descriptor, data_filename, IN_MODIFY);
  if (watch_descriptor < 0) return nullptr;
  char buf[4096] __attribute__((aligned(__alignof__(inotify_event))));

  while (true) {
    // Read new events.
    const inotify_event* event;
    ssize_t numRead = read(file_descriptor, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (numRead <= 0) return nullptr;

    // For each event, do stuff.
    for (int i = 0; i < numRead; i += sizeof(inotify_event) + event->len) {
      event = reinterpret_cast<inotify_event*>(&buf[i]);

      // Critical section!
      int fd = AquireLock(lock_filename);

      // Read from the file.
      std::string line;
      std::ifstream data_file(data_filename);
      if (data_file.is_open()) {
        while (getline(data_file, line)) {
          std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }
        data_file.close();

        // Clear the file by opening then closing without writing to it.
        std::ofstream erase_data_file(data_filename);
        erase_data_file.close();
        std::cout << "file cleared." << std::endl;
      }
      ReleaseLock(fd, lock_filename);
      // Critical section over!
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}

int main(int argv, char** argc) {
  // Set up other thread.
  pthread_t thread;
  int rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, ConsumerThread, nullptr);
  if (rc) return rc;

  // Producer thread: Periodically write to a file.
  while (true) {
    sleep(3);
    // Critical section!
    int fd = AquireLock(lock_filename);

    // Write some text to a file
    std::ofstream data_file(data_filename);
    int counter = 0;
    if (data_file.is_open()) {
      std::cout << "Writing to file.\n";
      data_file << "This is some example data. " << counter++ << "\n";
      data_file.close();
    }
    ReleaseLock(fd, lock_filename);
    // Critical section over!
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

One idea I had was to disable tracking of modify events at the start of the consumer thread's critical section with `inotify_rm_watch`, then re-add it right before leaving the critical section. This doesn't seem to work though. Even with the events disabled, modify events are still getting triggered and I'm not sure why.

I've also considered just using a boolean to see if there was any file contents while consuming the file, and only clearing the file if it wasn't empty. This felt kind of hacky since it's still doing a second unnecessary iteration of the loop, but if I can't find a better solution I might just go with that. Ideally there would be a way to have only the producer thread's modifications trigger events, while the consumer could have it's own file modifications somehow ignored or disabled, but I'm not sure how to achieve that effect.

Comment: That's not C code.

Comment: wouldn't it be enough to simply check that the file is not empty before consuming it?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: That doesn't really matter. The underlying API's my question is about are C libraries, not C++ libraries. My sample code was just there to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @KarstenKoop: That's basically what I suggested in my final paragraph. I was just wondering if there was a more correct solution.

Comment: In general, I found the "modify" events to be useless. Instead, waiting for the file to be closed again is more useful. However, why don't you just use a pipe? Or possibly some higher-level IPC mechanism like ZeroMQ, which can reliably transfer messages over shared memory and thus avoid truncated messages.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Using close might be a good idea. I'll give that a try. As for using a  pipe, I don't have a guarantee that the producer and consumers will be active at the same time, and I need to ensure that the data from the producer gets scooped up by the consumer when it eventually does run, so saving it out to a file seemed like the right way to go.